# Can we connect Emacs with Yahoo, Facebook and MSN?

Tags: emacs

I wonder, can we do chatting using facebook,msn and yahoo inside Emacs? I just Google a bit, and found http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-im/EmacsYahooChat.html, but there's no download available.

What are your solution for it?

Thanks.

Comment: Emacs and Facebook?!  Oh the humanity :-)

Comment: ^_^ Yes, indeed both are coliding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's great support for [XMPP in emacs](http://emacs-jabber.sourceforge.net/).  Facebook has XMPP support.  There are gateways for the others from XMPP.

I doubt anyone's put a lot of effort into proprietary protocols.

Comment: great! I'll do a check on it!

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion: [bitlbee](http://www.bitlbee.org), an IRC server that proxies a number of chat protocols, including msn, yahoo, xmpp/jabber, twitter, and oscar. With this setup, you can use one of the fine IRC clients available for Emacs such as ERC or rcirc. I use ERC.

Comment: should be a try. I'll check that too!